How to correctly update OpenSSH version on virtual machine
I am currently running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS with ssh version:
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022

I want to update the current OpenSSH version to 9.2 or latter. This is requirement in order to setup PDC with my grafana server.
I have found a simmillar post:
Upgrade OpenSSH from v8.9 to v9.3 on 22.04.2 LTS?
However, I am just slightly concerned whether that is correct. In particular:
sudo systemctl stop sshd
sudo apt-get remove openssh-server openssh-client

Is it safe to execute those commands on a virtual server that I am connect via SSH? Will I not be disconnected from the VM?
There is also another post:
Is possible to upgrade openssh-server OpenSSH_7.6p1, to OpenSSH_8.0p1?
That explains how to update OpenSSH version but different method:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev
sudo mkdir /var/lib/sshd
sudo chmod -R 700 /var/lib/sshd/
sudo chown -R root:sys /var/lib/sshd/
wget -c https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-8.9p1.tar.gz
tar -xzf openssh-8.9p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-8.9p1/
sudo apt install libpam0g-dev libselinux1-dev libkrb5-dev
./configure --with-kerberos5 --with-md5-passwords --with-pam --with-selinux --with-privsep-path=/var/lib/sshd/ --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh
make
sudo make install

I would like to clarify which process is the most optimal and safe to use to update OpenSSH on the client that I am currently connected via SSH

I figured it was not going to be straight forward :/ The error I am getting from when trying to run grafana PDC (private data source) instance on my Virtual machine:
level=error caller=main.go:159 ts=2024-08-22T13:33:28.452451634+03:00 err="invalid SSH version: OpenSSH version must be greater or equal to 9.2, current version: 8.9"```

so I shall upgrade to later Ubuntu ?

Suggestion: Plan to migrate to Ubuntu 24.04. Either by spinning up a new VM, or by migrating the old one. Best path depends upon the type of VM and your remote host.

So I wont be able to do sudo do-release-upgrade until a few weeks/months later till they finally release the 24.04 LTS? According to: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases it is already out but its not available to upgrade on my VM as I am getting: There is no development version of an LTS available.

"Plan" because 24.04.1 was bumped to 29 August, a mere six days. 24.04 was released back in April -- you can fresh-install it right now. You just can't upgrade your old 22.04 yet. LTS release-upgrades are always three months later to keep the support burden manageable -- we are volunteers. Cease using the -d flag unless you have read the manpage and really want a development release.

Okay thanks. Il wait for August 29 and then try to upgrade.
